# C# SqlBulkCopy types mismatch

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I have a DataTable which has 10 columns, and after I add some rows in it, I want to add it to the database using `SqlBulkCopy`.

My problem is that in the DataTable I have strings and some fields in the database are decimal and date respectively. Is there a way to convert them to the desired data types?

Comment: How do you add the columns to the datatable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When programmatically adding columns to your DataTable, you can specify type:-

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FieldName", typeof(System.Decimal));
```

These will be honored when you perform the bulk copy.

**EDIT**

In response to user comment.

When populating the DataRow with information, an explicit conversion is *only* required if the source data doesn't match the target field.

If the types are the same, you can just assign it.

e.g.

```
// With a decimal field, decimal target
Decimal myNum = 123;
// Works fine - assuming the Price datacolumn has been set up as a System.Decimal
row["Price"] = myNum;
```

Comment: Ok, and then, adding a row, how will that look like? I have all the info I need in a string[], so I assume I have to convert it before adding it. For example: DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
row["Price"] = Convert.ToDecimal(blanketInfo[4]); dataTable.Rows.Add(row); I will need to do that for all the data I have, or is there another way?

Comment: Depends on what type blanketInfo[4] is.  If the type doesn't reflect your target field type, then you will need to convert it.  However, if it is already a decimal, you can just assign it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may be creating the columns in the DataTable in code (as opposed to Filling via a DataAdapter which would set the column data types appropriately).

If that's the case, then can you not just create the DataColumns with the correct data types to start with, instead of all strings...and then ensure when you add rows to it, you convert the data into the appropriate type?

i.e. get to the point where your DataTable has the correct types and data in correctly, so SqlBulkCopy can then blast it into the DB with data already in the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

was having the same problem where in I was suppose to copy data from an excel file which had strings and I wanted them to be stored in the database as double. I have pasted the code related to the question below :-

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

//Read Data from First Sheet

```
    connExcel.Open();
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "] ";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();


        Convert.ToDouble(dt.Columns["Product"]);
```

//where product(product temperature) is the a column whose datatype in the database is float and in the excel file is string.